# adding class on screen size with javascript not working

Tags: javascript

```
var d = document.getElementById('promo5');

var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;


function mobileViewUpdate() {

if (viewportWidth <= 700) {
    d.className += (" .promo5-mobile");
}else (viewportWidth >= 700) {
    d.className += ("");
}
}


window.onload = mobileViewUpdate();
window.onresize = mobileViewUpdate();
```

to add a class to this div

```
div id="promo5" class="promo5"
```

so it can to this on the mobile size of my website

```
.promo5-mobile {
display: none;
}
```

Just cant figure out why it wont add this class, or maybe its adding it but is still displaying, I want it to not display. It works when I run it on my browser console but not on my code. I have checked if my js file works and it does.I am a beginner so it maybe something really basic.

EDIT: changed wrongly worded if statement to else if, moved the viewportWidth variable inside the function, check with browser inspector and its still not adding the class. Will use media queries unless someone finds the problem.

Comment: Do you know you can make the same with CSS media queries?

Comment: yea I have made queries. The problem is the mobile version is my main css, while the desktop size is in my media query. I want to use javascript to take things off the mobile size but have them in the desktop size, If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the errors are many there:

1. move `var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;` into the `mobileViewUpdate` function. Otherwise its value is set once at the page load.
2. call function on resize as `window.onresize = mobileViewUpdate`, no brackets
3. correct condition statement - no brackets after else
4. className should not be adding `promo5-mobile` every time your resize window which is already small, and don't forget to remove that class if you resize it back to medium-large

This should work:

```
var d = document.getElementById('promo5');

function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if ( viewportWidth <= 700 ) {
        if ( d.className.indexOf(" promo5-mobile") === -1 ) {
            d.className += (" promo5-mobile");
        }
    } else {
        if ( d.className.indexOf(" promo5-mobile") > -1 ) {
            d.className = d.className.replace(" promo5-mobile", "");
        }
    }
}

window.onload = mobileViewUpdate;
window.onresize = mobileViewUpdate;
```

Comment: didnt work :( why is there a -1, ===, and indexof, im pretty confused

Comment: this is how we check we have or have no that class in the `className` already, so we add it only if it is not there (on small) and remove if it is there (on medium-large).   it works, please check if you copied the code correctly - I made some amendments to it

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a `.` in the class name. If you're referencing your class as such `.promo5-mobile` in your CSS, then your javascript should be `d.className += (" promo5-mobile");`, without the `.`.

**Edit:** In addition, as Nikolay specifies in his answer, you're only setting `viewportWidth` when the page loads. You're calling your javascript function when the page is resized, but you're not updating `viewportWidth`, so the results of the function will never change.

**Edit 2:** If I may ask, why are you using Javascript to hide an element instead of a simple CSS `@media` query?

In your main CSS:

```
#promo5 {
  display: none;
}

  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    #promo5 {
      display: block;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @FransB Check out Nikolay's answer. You're setting the `viewportWidth` when the page loads, and then never updating it again.

Comment: ok thanks, I moved it inside the function and its still displaying the div, is there a way I can check if its adding the class at all.

Comment: Shrink the window, right click on the element and go to "Inspect Element", and see if it has the class. Can I ask why you're using Javascript instead of `@media` queries?

Comment: @FransB So why not have a `display: none;` in your mobile CSS, and then in your desktop version do a `display: block;` or `display: inline;`?

Comment: I used inspect element and its not adding the class

Comment: because my mobile css is my main css. And im using flexbox. But I will try to see what happens

Comment: @FransB see my updated CSS. You can write a rule in your main css that hides the div *always*, and then override it with a media query that says `(min-width: 700px)` - Always hide it, but if the window is above 700px, show it.

Comment: Thanks, your media query method works, though it did cause some small issue with flexbox. Its just weird that my javascript wont add a class.

Comment: @FransB Javascript is a bit more complicated though. Every single time you resize the window even 1 pixel in your example, you'd be adding a class. You could add the class hundreds of times using your original method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you wrote wrong the if/ else statement.Instead of else, you should use else if, or you can use the else without the (viewportWidth >= 700). See below:

**Edit 1**: Use classlist instead of className. This will make your javascript add a class.See below:

```
    function mobileViewUpdate() {

if (viewportWidth <= 700) {
    d.classList.add("promo5-mobile");
} else {
    d.classList.remove("promo5-mobile");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `if (viewportWidth >= 700)` part